# Right way to upload files with ember js and with support of IE8

Tags: file-upload, ember.js, internet-explorer-8

I have problem with uploading files from my ember.js frontend to grails backend. I can't use any of ember plugins like ember-uploader because of supporting IE8. Any advices how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BlueImp's jQuery File Upload claims it supports IE 6+.  Read more about it: 
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

I use it via an Ember component like this:

```
{{file-upload uploadUrl=uploadUrl filename="files" 
    buttonText="Upload files" 
    hiddenName="fileId" hiddenValue=fileId
    uploaded="filesUploaded"}}
```

and initialize the plugin in the component's `didInsertElement`:

```
didInsertElement: function() {
    var self = this;
    this.$('#'+this.get('inputId')).fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: this.get('uploadUrl'),
        formData: function() {
            return [{name: self.get('hiddenName'), value: self.get('hiddenValue')}];
        },
        done: function(e, data) {
            self.sendAction('uploaded', data.result);
            self.markCompleted(data.result.filenames);
        },
        fail: function (e, data) {
            self.sendAction('failed', data.result);
        },
        add: function(e, data) {
            data.process().done(function () {
                data.submit();
            });
        },
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for response kielni, but I used different approach than yours.
I used solution from this blog post: [Cross-browser AJAX uploads with Ember.js and mOxie](http://scribu.net/blog/cross-browser-uploads-ember-moxie.html)


And code in component that worked for me:

```
var fileInput = new mOxie.FileInput({
            browse_button: this.$('.file-pick-button').get(0),
            multiple: false
        });

        fileInput.onchange = function (e) {
            var file = fileInput.files[0];
            var reader = new mOxie.FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = function () {
                ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    timeout: 5000,
                    url: config.serverURL + '/files/',
                    data: {
                        transportID: id,
                        filename: file.name,
                        file: reader.result
                    }
                });
            };
            reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
        };
        fileInput.init();
```